# How do I make a div go to the rightside?

Tags: html, css

I have an image in a div, and I want it to go to the right side. Right now it just keeps on sticking to the left side, overlapping another image in a div. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Could you maybe add your code?

Comment: Without your code I don't know if it will work, but you could try adding right:0 to your div.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `text-align: right` to align image to right side.

```css
.myDiv{
text-align: right
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1254140/pexels-photo-1254140.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" width="200px" height="200px">
</div>
```